# RAM is loose in slots: replace it or replace motherboard?

Tags: memory, motherboard, hardware-failure

I have an ECS mini-ITX (H55H-I) motherboard with Geil DDR3 RAM. I've had it for about a year for an HTPC build, but I haven't used it very much because it's had intermittent problems that I could not diagnose. I already asked one question about it on here and replaced the power supply as suggested. Didn't help. It had already passed memtest (one of the first things I did) multiple times but I tried it again anyway and to my surprise there were a lot of failures. I swapped sticks and slots to try and figure out what was the faulty piece but it just kept passing on every combination. Then I discovered that if I nudged the RAM at all, the video would start to mess up (onboard video, so system RAM is shared) and if I pushed a bit harder, the whole computer rebooted. I never pushed anywhere close to as hard as I had to push to insert the ram in the slots. I also ran memtest and wiggled the RAM on my main desktop computer and nothing happened.

I visually inspected the RAM connectors and they all seem fine, and I can't really see the motherboard's connectors. My first instinct is to replace the motherboard because the slots are more likely to be bad than the RAM.

Does anyone here have experience with a problem like this? What happened in your case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

considering that ram is one solid circuit board, and more likely to snap than warp, it is probably the motherboard slots that are at fault.

The closest thing i have is snapped retaining clips, and a particular mobo that would kill any ram put into a specific slot.